# How can I detect a grid of filled circles?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, vision

Given an image of a connect-4 board I'd like to recognize and output the board's state (a 6 by 7 matrix). The first approach I tried was based on finding the circles and then looking for a grid pattern in their centroids.

This is the open-cv function I'm using:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(bw_im,
                               cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,
                               dp=DP,
                               minDist=MIN_DIST,
                               minRadius=MIN_RADIUS,
                               maxRadius=MAX_RADIUS)
```

I add non-maximum suppression, but the results are not great.

**Is there a better way than dealing with Hough circles directly, perhaps there is some sort of *filled circularity* morphological operation that I don't know of.**

Here's an example input image:

[image]

You can assume that the input image has been cropped and has similar margins as above (I have another piece of code that takes care of this).

Comment: Circles, why does it have to be circles? Might be simpler to segment out red/yellow blobs and use their centroids.

Comment: Have a look at `cv2.inRange`, e.g. [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/04/opencv-python-color-detection/), You can easily segment red and yellow (and eventually blue) converting your image to HSV first.

Comment: i would recommend HSV color space too and either segmentation or contour detection etc.

Answer (score 0):

If Hough isn't a requirement, Id suggest implementing a ray-casting algorithm as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

The general steps are:

1. Create a mask for the red circles
2. Run ray-casting on `x` columns spaced `y` apart to determine # and position of reds
3. Repeat steps 1 & 2 for yellow

Since you're working in RGB, the color contrast should be enough to give you good results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your grid will maintain its position the easiest way would be to setup a fixed region of interest for every slot and measure their hue values every time you change something.